# How to call a global variable in to function in C?

Tags: c

I'm starting at the word of programming so I'm reading a book about programming in C, it says that if I want to call a global variable into a function I need to call the global variable with (`::`) before the name... in terminal shows this:

**funcion2.c:17:57: error: expected expression before ‘::’ token
17 |         printf("value of global variable is %d\n",::k);
thaks.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f1(void);
int K=5;
void main()
{
    int I;
    for(I=1; I<=3; I++)
    {
        f1();
    }
    void f1(void)
    {
        int k=2;
        K+=K;
        printf("VALUE IS: %d\n",k);
        ::K=::K+K;                        // <-
        printf("VALUE IS %d\n",::k);      // <-
    }
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. `::` does not mean anything in C, and you don't need it to access globals in C++. Get a better book.

Comment: please don't use `*` to bold code. It doesnt work and messes up the code

Comment: Get rid of the two occurrences of `::` - they are used only for C++ (and not even useful even if this were C++ code).

Comment: You have several "typos". `int main`, `void f1()` declared inside `main`...

Comment: Also using variables names `k` and `K` is not a great idea - there are plenty of other letters in the alphabet,

Comment: You have a global `K` (uppercase), but a local `k` (lowercase). is it intended or another typo?

Comment: In C the case of the letters in the names matters. `k` and `K` are different variables.

Comment: Well the book is taking as a example like when you have two variables of the same name in the function and in the main program you can use :: to differentiate the variables.

Comment: If it's a C language book then I wish you well with that. (I suggest you rip it up and use it as bedding for your pet hamster.) What's next, `class`, `template` ?

Comment: 1. Your book is not about C, it's about C++. You can't learn C from it. 2. You don't have two variables of the same name in either language.

Answer (score -2):

The global variable is called before the `main()` function, and that beeing said, heres an example of programm using global variable in `main()` and in funtions:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func_1();
void func_2();
int a, b = 10;  // declaring and initializing global variables

int main()
{
    printf("Global a = %d\n", a);
    printf("Global b = %d\n\n", b);

    func_1();
    func_2();

    // signal to operating system program ran fine
    return 0;
}

void func_1()
{
    printf("From func_1() Global a = %d\n", a);
    printf("From func_1() Global b = %d\n\n", b);
}

void func_2()
{
    int a = 5;
    printf("Inside func_2() a = %d\n", a);
}
```

Output:

```
Global a = 0
Global b = 10

From func_1() Global a = 0
From func_1() Global b = 10

Inside func_2() a = 5
```

In line 4, `a` and `b` are declared as two global variables of type `int`. The variable `a` will be automatically initialized to 0. You can use variables `a` and `b` inside any function. Notice that inside function `func_2()` there is a local variable with the same name as a global variable. When there is a conflict between the global variable and local variable, the local variable gets the precedence, that's why inside the `func_2()` value of local variable `a` is printed.

Unlike local variables, global variables are not destroyed as soon as the function ends. They are available to any function until the program is executing.

Comment: your `func_2` simply demonstrates *shadowing* and doesn't really help explain things. because it works for **everything**, not just local/global variables. try it with with parameterized methods, and it'll still "override" the argument.